# DB2 AS400 v7r1 connection from .NET framework 4.6, VS2017

Tags: ado.net, db2, nuget, ibm-midrange

I'm very new with DB2 but have started a project that require to manipulate DB2 Database in AS400 v7r1 iSeries.
I'm trying to use the `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries` nuget to make a connection but no luck. My connection string in `Web.config` looks like

```
<add key="ConnectionString" 
 value="Provider=IBMDA400;Password=pwd;User ID=user;Data Source=server_ip_add;Transport Product=Client Access;SSL=DEFAULT;Default Collection=default_schema"/>
```

and I am using it like this:

```
var myConnection = new iDB2Connection(connectionString);
```

The returned error is 'The connectionstring property is invalid'
There are some other nugets named `IBM.Data.Db2` and `IBM.Data.Db.Provider` but I haven't tried them. These seem to work with .NET 4.0 but I'm not sure they can work with AS400 v7r1.

I have tried using DSDriver and VSAI but cannot create an EF model.

Could you please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following:

***App.config:***

```
<add key="iConnectionString" value="DataSource=MyMachine; UserID=TheUser; 
Password=ThePassword; Naming=System; CheckConnectionOnOpen=true; 
DataCompression=True; Pooling=False" />
```

using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries;
...

***connect:***

```
    private iDB2Connection iCon;
    ...
        if (iCon == null || iCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                iCon = new iDB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["iConnectionString"]);
                if (iCon == null) rv = false;
                else
                {
                    iCon.Open();
                    if (iCon == null || iCon.State != ConnectionState.Open) rv = false;
                }
            }
            catch (iDB2CommErrorException ee)
            {
                //var Message = ee.MessageCode + ":" + ee.Message + "\n\rSQL-Status: " + ee.SqlState;
                rv = false;
            }
        }
```

***insert:***

```
        try
        {
            iDB2Command iCmd = new iDB2Command("INSERT INTO EDIFSP (TFRNUM, FILENAME, PROCSTS, PROCDTTM, SND_ID, RCV_ID, TFRDIR, IFCTYPE, IFCVRSN, MAPNAME, CRTDTTM, TFRDTTM) " +
                                               "VALUES(@TFRNUM, @FILENAME, @PROCSTS, @PROCDTTM, @SND_ID, @RCV_ID, @TFRDIR, @IFCTYPE, @IFCVRSN, @MAPNAME, @CRTDTTM, @TFRDTTM)", iCon);
            iCmd.DeriveParameters();
            iCmd.Parameters["@TFRNUM"].Value = fs.TransferNumber;
            iCmd.Parameters["@FILENAME"].Value = fs.FileName;
            iCmd.Parameters["@PROCSTS"].Value = fs.Status;
            iCmd.Parameters["@PROCDTTM"].Value = DateTime.Now;
            iCmd.Parameters["@SND_ID"].Value = fs.SenderID;
            iCmd.Parameters["@RCV_ID"].Value = fs.ReceiverID;
            iCmd.Parameters["@TFRDIR"].Value = fs.TransferDirection;
            iCmd.Parameters["@IFCTYPE"].Value = fs.InterfaceType;
            iCmd.Parameters["@IFCVRSN"].Value = fs.InterfaceVersion;
            iCmd.Parameters["@MAPNAME"].Value = fs.MappingName;
            iCmd.Parameters["@CRTDTTM"].Value = fs.CreationDateTime;
            iCmd.Parameters["@TFRDTTM"].Value = fs.TransferDateTime;
            iCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            iCmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (iDB2SQLErrorException ee)
        {
            //var Message = ee.MessageCode + ":" + ee.Message + "\n\rSQL-Status: " + ee.SqlState;
        }
        catch (iDB2CommErrorException ee)
        {
            //var Message = ee.MessageCode + ":" + ee.Message + "\n\rSQL-Status: " + ee.SqlState;
        }
```

Hope that helps. Be sure to have IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll and IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.xml in your project (or path)...

Comment: The code is fine but I have to install IBM iAccess For Windows. Just the dll doesn't work for me